# JAXB empty element unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, exception, jaxb

The problem is in the following :

I get the soap response with empty element inside (e.g. `... <someDate /> ...` )
and as a result exception is being throwed when JAXB wants to parse this element 
instead to set the appropriate field with `null` value.

How to configure JAXB to treat empty elements as null ?
Can we do this with JAXB only (not using some third-party workarounds)

Comment: Can you share some more information? The Exception Stacktrace and some code maybe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Base Problem

Empty `String` is not a valid value for the `xsd:date` type.  To be valid with the XML schema an optional element should be represented as an absent node.,

---

### Why the Base Problem is Impacting You

All JAXB implementations will recognize that empty `String` is not a valid value for `xsd:date`.  They do this by reporting it to an instance of `ValidationEventHandler`.  You can see this yourself by doing the following:

```
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The implementation of JAX-WS you are using, leverages [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as the JAXB provider.  And in the version you are using MOXy will by default throw an exception when a `ValidationEvent` of severity `ERROR` is encountered instead of `FATAL_ERROR` like the reference implementation.  This has since been fixed in the following bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/369994

---

### Work Around

If you are using the JAXB APIs directly you could simply override the default `ValidationEventHandler`.  In a JAX-WS environment a `XmlAdapter` can be used to provide custom conversion logic.  We will leverage an `XmlAdapter` to override how the conversion to/from `Date` is handled.

**XmlAdapter (DateAdapter)**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>{

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if(v.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return dateFormat.parse(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v) {
            return null;
        }
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

}
```

**Java Model (Root)**

The `XmlAdapter` is referenced using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  If you wish this `XmlAdapter` to apply to all instances of `Date` you can register it at the package level (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html).

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)
    private Date abc;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=DateAdapter.class, type=Date.class)
    private Date qwe;

}
```

---

### Demo Code

Below is a standalone example you can run to see that everything works.

**jaxb.properties**

In a standalone example to use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.propeties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <abc></abc>
    <qwe>2013-09-05</qwe>
</root>
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum18617998/input.xml");
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Note that in the marshalled XML the `Date` field that was null was marshalled as an absent element (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <qwe>2013-09-05</qwe>
</root>
```