# JAXB-Return the entire XML object even if i don't have values

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I'm trying to return an xml response with JAXB and the implementation looks like in the example bellow. My question is: There is a way to return the whole xml without setting a value on the field?

```
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<Ns2AnfrageBonitaetsauskunftAntwortType> getResponse(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<Ns2AnfrageBonitaetsauskunftTyp> request) {

        Ns2AnfrageBonitaetsauskunftAntwortType response = new Ns2AnfrageBonitaetsauskunftAntwortType();
        response.setSchufaReferenz("test2");
        response.setTeilnehmerreferenz("test1");
        response.setAktionsdaten("test3");
        Ns3BonitaetsauskunftType bonita = new Ns3BonitaetsauskunftType();
        bonita.setTeilnehmerkennung("test4");

        Ns3VerarbeitungsinformationType verar = new Ns3VerarbeitungsinformationType();
        verar.setErgebnistyp("test7");
        bonita.setVerarbeitungsinformation(verar);

        Ns3VerbraucherdatenAuskunftType daten = new Ns3VerbraucherdatenAuskunftType();
        daten.setPersonOhneGeburtsdatum("test6");
        bonita.setVerbraucherdaten(daten);
        response.setReaktion(bonita);
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        return objectFactory.createBonitaetsauskunft(response);
    }
```

At the moment the response look like this:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ns3:Bonitaetsauskunft xmlns:ns3="http://ifd-schema.de/BonitaetsauskunftSCHUFA">
         <SchufaReferenz>test2</SchufaReferenz>
         <Teilnehmerreferenz>test1</Teilnehmerreferenz>
         <Aktionsdaten xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">test3</Aktionsdaten>
         <Reaktion>
            <Teilnehmerkennung>test4</Teilnehmerkennung>
            <Verbraucherdaten>
               <PersonOhneGeburtsdatum>test6</PersonOhneGeburtsdatum>
            </Verbraucherdaten>
            <Verarbeitungsinformation>
               <Ergebnistyp>test7</Ergebnistyp>
            </Verarbeitungsinformation>
         </Reaktion>
      </ns3:Bonitaetsauskunft>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have a lot of more field on which i don't want to set a value but i want them to be in the response. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Having XmlAddapter for each relevant type. The question is, for example for String, how do you then distinguish between an empty String and a null-String? Anyway look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921196/jaxb-empty-element-unmarshalling

Answer (score 0):

You can add to each property `nillable` attribut using `@XmlElement(nillable = true)` annotation. From [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_element.asp):

> Optional. Specifies whether an explicit null value can be assigned to
>   the element. True enables an instance of the element to have the null
>   attribute set to true. The null attribute is defined as part of the
>   XML Schema namespace for instances. Default is false

Fields with this attribute are print as `<value xsi:nil="true"/>`. Small example:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JaxbApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Root dataFile = new Root();
        dataFile.setPerson(new Person());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION, XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI);

        marshaller.marshal(dataFile, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "roo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Root {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private Integer id;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private String value;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private Person person;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Person {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    private String lastName;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<roo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id xsi:nil="true"/>
    <value xsi:nil="true"/>
    <person>
        <name xsi:nil="true"/>
        <lastName xsi:nil="true"/>
    </person>
</roo>
```

In that case you need to change your `XSD`/`WSDL` document and add this attribute to each primitive field. Of course, you still need to create new `POJO` instance like `new Person()` in above example. You can of course set each property in class to some kind of default value `private String value = "";` or write reflection tool which travers all properties and set to some custom values.

See also:

- [Represent null value as empty element in xml jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366054/represent-null-value-as-empty-element-in-xml-jaxb)